# Wp admin - Set default value to 999 in comments

Tags: functions, comments, wp-admin, screen-layout

When you are at the comments menu in wp-admin you only see 20 comments at the time, so if you want to delete alla comments you can **ONLY** mark the 20 comments you see on current page. It dosent mark comments that are on the next page.

Found a solution but dont know where to look for it

In WP-admin -> Screen layout there you can see that its only set to 20 comments a page.
I know that i could just access the screen layout and set it to maximum (999 comments a page).

Now the question is can I set that value (999) to default for every user i create ? Or just basicly for the whole network?

**Follow question:**:
If its possible, then whats the best way to do it ?

**NOTE** : Im using latest WordPress version with Multisite network.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
add_filter('edit_comments_per_page', 'return_999');
function return_999(){
    return 999;
}
```

since the user options are filtered in the `WP_List_Table::get_items_per_page()` class method :

```
/**
 * Get number of items to display on a single page
 *
 * @since 3.1.0
 * @access protected
 *
 * @return int
 */
function get_items_per_page( $option, $default = 20 ) {
        $per_page = (int) get_user_option( $option );
        if ( empty( $per_page ) || $per_page < 1 )
                $per_page = $default;

        return (int) apply_filters( $option, $per_page );
}
```

So you could do the same for `edit_post_per_page` and `edit_page_per_page`.

Or if you have other custom post types: `edit_{CPT}_per_page`.

Answer (score 1):

That value is set on a per user basis and saved as user meta. We can intercept and modify it to a fixed value using the filter [`get_{$meta_type}_metadata`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/meta.php#L274).

Create a [Must Use plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) and it will be active in all the Network:

```
add_filter( 'get_user_metadata', 'comments_per_page_wpse_95420', 10, 4 );

function comments_per_page_wpse_95420( $check, $object_id, $meta_key, $single )
{ 
    if( 'edit_comments_per_page' == $meta_key )
        return 999;

    return $check;
}
```

Related Q&A: [How to list ALL Pages in the dashboard?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/23503/12615)